# datetime index in plotting doesn't work. why?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I want to plot one month of data [one data per hour. the dataset is over one year]. why is this code not working?

```
df_pv["Zeit"] = pd.to_datetime(df_pv["Zeit"])
df_pv["Zeit"].min(), df_pv["Zeit"].max()
[Out] (Timestamp('2020-01-01 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'))
df_pv.set_index("Zeit")
df_pv['2020-04-01 01:00:00':'2020-04-30 01:00:00'].plot()
```

Error message:

> "TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [2020-01-01 01:00:00] of type str"

thanks a lot!!

Comment: can you try with `df_pv[pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 01:00:00'):pd.Timestamp('2020-04-30 01:00:00')].plot()` instead?

Comment: convert the string slice to a datatime

Comment: i tried it: "TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [2020-01-01 01:00:00] of type Timestamp" @mechanical_meat

Comment: i convert the string into datatime in the first line [code]. or is it not working? @Golden Lion

Comment: [in] df_pv["Zeit"] = pd.to_datetime(df_pv["Zeit"])
df_pv["Zeit"].head(1) [out] 0 2020-01-01 01:00:00
Name: Zeit, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: your plot is slicing using strings rather than datetimes. use df_pv[pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 01:00:00'):pd.Timestamp('2020-04-30 01:00:00')].plot() as previous suggested

Comment: i guess it's an index problem because it now tells sth about rangeindex. and when i try df_pv.index = pd.to_datetime(df_pv.index) i'm suddenly in the 1970's xD.

Answer (score 0):

convert Zeit to datatime using pd.To_DateTime()

```
df_pv=pd.DataFrame()
df_pv["Zeit"] = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'))

df_pv.set_index("Zeit", inplace=True)
df_pv['y']=np.random.randn(len(df_pv))
df_pv.plot()
```